# Change Gravity of SKSpriteNode without modifying physicsWorld gravity?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to change the gravity of a single SKSpriteNode without affecting the rest of the scene. The only way to change gravity that I've seen is changing the gravity of the PhysicsWorld, but this makes the gravity affect everything. How can  I change the gravity for a single SKSpriteNode without affecting the rest of the sprites in my scene?

Comment: When you say you want to change gravity. What is that actual effect that you want from doing that?

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to flip the gravity, so that the sprite is moving up rather than down.

Comment: I would suggest not using gravity but using a force instead. You can apply a force to objects in any direction and they are applied on a single object. Take a look at the SKAction applyForce method.